# Strange Container Height Issue

Tags: css, html

Short of adding in some jQuery to change the height of the #inner_page container, how can I do the same in CSS?

I need that container's height to be the height of the inner .content_text container.

http://new.o7thwebdesign.com

(let me know of you need the CSS code, I assume if you're here you know how to view source...)

Comment: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visudet.html#the-height-property

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you change the style of the inner_body to

```
display: table;
```

It should do the trick.

Comment: would throwing a 'clear' div after 'content-text do the same?

Comment: I ask, because in IE8 & 7, it appears to throw off the rest of the layout...  the floats no longer work for the 'Navigation', and the content...

Comment: Adding a <div style="clear:both"></div> after the </article> should work as well.